# Hamiltonian-inspired energy function for power grid stability

Tags: power, energy, system

I'm looking at [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5618968) paper which proposes an energy function for a 3-bus power system example. I'm trying to replicate the results in the paper but am uncertain about the `D` parameters in Sec III. In particular, the authors verify that with a certain `A` matrix adjusting the gradient dynamics, the model has a stable equilibrium, but I'm confused about the `D` parameters in this matrix.

Here is the relevant section:[image] [image]

EDIT1: it looks like the `D` terms are some sort of rotor damping.

EDIT2 (follow up question): I'm having trouble tying out the dimensions of the `A3bus` matrix to the `Abus` matrix. Specifically, the dimensions of `Mg` seem off. It appears that the `g` means both slack and generator node, but then I don't see how to fit `A3bus` into the `Abus` structure. Any advice?

EDIT3: [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7444204) paper helps somewhat but is still a bit unclear on the interpretation of the `Pi` matrices.

Thanks!

Comment: What page specifically were you looking at?

Comment: Sorry, just realized I uploaded a different but related link. Let me extract the pages of the paper I'm referring to

Answer (score 0):

Stub of an answer right now, but the `D` parameters refer to machine damping values in the classical swing equations. The `epsilon` parameter is a singular perturbation of an algebraic constraint related to the reactive power flow.